# How to ignore accelerometer and override hardware disabling keyboard?

Tags: arch-linux, linux-kernel, keyboard, kernel-modules, hardware

My laptop is configured to disable the keyboard when it is in tablet mode. This would normally be beneficial, but my laptop's accelerometer/hinge sensor is broken. This means the keyboard never works. I know this is the problem, because when flip the screen around(it's a convertible) the keyboard starts working.

I think I can fix this if Linux could override the the hardware(bios?) and ignore the sensor or enable the keyboard. This was possible on windows by disabling the accelerometer/sensor through regedit or command prompt.

So is there a way to configure Linux to disable/ignore the accelerometer?

My laptop is a HP Spectre x360 15(the 2016 model). 
I am on the arch linux installation disk.

Comment: how do you disable the sensor in windows?

Comment: @jsotola You go to device manager and disable the intel integrated sensor hub

Comment: you said that is could be disabled through command prompt ... what was the command? ... a google search may find the linux equivalent